# asynch lambda does not producing expected result

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, async-await, c#-5.0

I have this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<Task<string>> getWordAsync = async () => "hello";

    Console.WriteLine(getWordAsync());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Taken from [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Async-C-5-0-Alex-Davies/dp/1449337163) book. Should this not print:

```
"hello"
```

instead of:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
```

Comment: The lambda works as expected. The return value of an async lambda is a Task that encapsulates the asynchronous operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DO NOT LOOK BEHIND THE CURTAIN!

The async/await keywords are not actually part of the common language specification (upon which the CLR is based), but are an artifact of the compiler.  The compiler rewrites your lambda to NOT return a string but in fact to return a `Task<string>`.  You should be able to see this clearly because

```
() => "hello"
```

is a `Func<string>` that returns a System.String on execution, whereas your variable is of type

```
Func<Task<string>>
```

Or, a `Func<T>` that, when executes, returns a `Task<string>`.

So, when you execute the func, the return result is a

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
```

(the Task`1[System.String] is exemplary of how generic types output their generic parameters)

So, the line

```
Console.WriteLine(getWordAsync());
```

is calling ToString() on an object of type `Task<string>`, which prints out the type's name.  This is expected.

The Task is actually running on a different thread, so you'll need to do one of the following to get out the result of the task:

```
Console.WriteLine(await getWordAsync());
```

(you must mark your Main method as `async` prior to using this version) or

```
Console.WriteLine(getWordAsync().Result);
```

The second will block the current thread until the result is available.  The first will execute the Console method on a different thread when the result becomes available.  That's another step down the async/await rabbit hole, btw.

Comment: Thanks excellent. I understand that the return is different in this case. .Result makes sense so does await a part of Console.WriteLine - Thanks for this!!!

Comment: Btw marking the entry point (Main) with async does not work nor does Console.WriteLine(await getWordAsync());

Comment: The entry point (`main`) cannot be marked as `async`; move the example into a new class and mark the method with `async` and it will work as Will described.

Comment: @csetzkorn Okay, so maybe the compiler doesn't like the entry point to be rewritten.  So move all your code EXCEPT the ReadLine call to a different `static async void` method.  Call that from within your Main method.  (don't use the await keyword in the Main method)

Answer (score 4):

To get the result of an `async` function you need to use the `await` keyword. Another options is to get the `Result` property of the `Task` object.

Comment: Thanks. yeah resharper complained about this but where do I put await. Have tried a few options.

Comment: I am trying whilst I read - sorry to ask questions ... I tried the await before I posted this btw.